# Icon not showing in main activity action bar

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

Icon is not showing in main activity action bar. What can be the possible reasons? I am trying to use different icons, one as a launcher and the other as a logo in main activity.

Answer (score 0):

With the AppCompat version 21 or with a Material theme it is normal.

The Action Bar follows the material design guidelines and uses a Toolbar.
As you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

```
The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is 
    discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.
```